# Mavericks bootloop after updating node through brew and chown usr/local

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mavericks

It had been a while since I rebooted my MacBook Air, and I was editing my bash profile, updating node through homebrew (in the process sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/ - first bad idea), and had added ntfs support (through ntfs-3g - yeah, terrible/dumb idea). It shut down normally, but gets stuck at the Apple log and the spinning gear indefinitely. I can boot into single user mode and even log in through launchctl (still in single user mode command prompt), and have verified the disk and permissions through recovery mode. When I boot in verbose mode, it loads until the Thunderbolt HPD packet information.

The last few lines of my verbose startup are

```
    AppleHSSPIController::HandleMessage Device Wake by Host
    hfs: mounted Macintosh HD on device root_device
    XCPM: registered
    Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad::start Start Succeeded
    [AppleMultitouchDevice::start] entered
    com.apple.launchd          1      com.apple.launchd              1      *** launchd[1] has started up. ***
    com.apple.launchd          1      com.apple.launchd              1      *** Verbose boot, will log to /dev/console. ***
    com.apple.launchd          1      com.apple.launchd              1      *** Shutdown loggin is enabled. ***
    ** /dev/rdisk0s2 (NO WRITE)
    ** Root file system
       Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-226.1.1).
    USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 000000000820 0x5ac 0x8406 0x820, 3
    Thunderbolt Self-Reset Count = 0xedefbe00
    IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8023f9bc00>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 11 unplug = 0
    IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8023f9bc00>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 11 unplug = 0
    IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8023f9bc00>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 12 unplug = 0
```

Anyone have any thoughts? I'd really rather not to a reinstall but will if I have to. I removed /etc/fstab since I thought that might be part of the problem, but it still isn't doing anything different.

Comment: Not sure why it's doing an `fsck_hfs` while booting - is there anything in /var/log with its output? What happens if you boot into single-user mode and try running `fsck_hfs` yourself? Also, when you boot in single-user mode, does it show `/dev/rdisk0s2` being mounted? I don't know why it would mount a write-only filesystem.